# For a given probability distribution, what is the meaning of "expected value equals to zero"?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

I was solving this problem:

"A player tosses 3 fair coins. He wins $ \$8$, if $3$ head occurs,  $\$3$ if $2$ heads occur, $\$1$ if $1$ head occurs. If the game is to be fair, how much should he loss, if no heads occur?"

I drew the probability distribution like this :

| 8 | 3 | 1 | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/8 | 3/8 | 3/8 | 1/8 |

Here z is the unknown amount the player will loose.

I was stuck here and asked my teacher, he said that the Expectation value i.e. E(x) = 0.
This solves this problem but I didn't understand the meaning of E(x) = 0.

Comment: See [Expected Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying $\mathbb E(X)=0$, it means that the player would not gain or lose on average, making it a fair game. Hence  $$8\cdot \frac18+3\cdot \frac38+1\cdot \frac38+z\cdot \frac18=0\longrightarrow z=-20$$